# How to get data of the merged cell given a cell indexes in java?

Tags: java, excel, merge, apache-poi, import-from-excel

I am having an excel file and i am using apache-poi to get data of the excel file so if i read any cell value then how to know if the cell is a merged cell and get the value of the merged cell

So i am trying to know weather a cell is a merged cell or not if it is  a merged cell i will try to get value of first row and first colon value of merged cell and if it is not a merged cell then i will directly get data of the value

like

```
String var = String.valueOf(sheet.getRow(Row).getCell(Cell));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two key methods you need:

- [Sheet.getMergedRegions()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getMergedRegions%28%29)
- [CellRangeAddressBase.isInRange(row,column)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddressBase.html#isInRange%28int,%20int%29) (merged regions extend from this)

Your code would just be something like:

```
public CellRangeAddress getMergedRegionForCell(Cell c) {
   Sheet s = c.getRow().getSheet();
   for (CellRangeAddress mergedRegion : s.getMergedRegions()) {
      if (mergedRegion.isInRange(c.getRowIndex(), c.getColumnIndex())) {
         // This region contains the cell in question
         return mergedRegion;
      }
   }
   // Not in any
   return null;
}
```

Then check if you get `null` back, if not read the first row and column of the region to know the top left cell of the region containing your cell of interest

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Sheet.getMergedRegions()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getMergedRegions%28%29) to determine all ranges of merged cells. Then you can use [CellRangeAddress.isInRange(row,column)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddressBase.html#isInRange%28int,%20int%29) on the returned ranges to check if the cell in question is a merged cell.

```java
public boolean isMergedCell(int row, int column) {
    for (CellRangeAddress range : sheet.getMergedRegions()) {
        if (range.isInRange(row, column)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: it gives me regions but if i give a cell how will it tell me it is a merged cell

Comment: is there any method that takes input as a cell's indexes(row number,colomn number) and returns if it is a merged cell or not

Comment: You can easily write such a method yourself, as shown above.

Comment: Why not use [CellRangeAddress.isInRange(row,column)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddressBase.html#isInRange%28int,%20int%29) to do the checking if the cell is in a merged region or not?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks! I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code (Kotlin) about how to get excel cell data as string taking into account that cell may be merged. I use this code for loading excel data into database.

```
fun getCellStr(sheet: XSSFSheet, cell: Cell): String {
    var res = ""
    val formatter = DataFormatter()
    var inRange = false
    for (range in sheet.getMergedRegions()) {
        if (range.isInRange(cell.rowIndex, cell.columnIndex)) {
            for (rIndex in range.firstRow..range.lastRow) {
                for (cIndex in range.firstColumn..range.lastColumn) {
                    res = "$res${formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(rIndex).getCell(cIndex))}"
                }
            }
            inRange = true
        }
    }
    if (!inRange) {
        res = formatter.formatCellValue(cell)
    }
    return res.trim()
}
```